# How resize div on mobile (click in the corner)?

Tags: html, mobile, resize

I need a div you can click in the corner and resize on android and iphone

thanks for your help

Comment: This is not a real question. We need more information.

Comment: this example, to open it in android, you can not resize the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/baBN9/ I need this functionality in android

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize You can't. Also, it would be a poor user experience.

Comment: It should be possible; In the page that show me http://caniuse.com/#search=drag I could not do the drag and drop, but if it exists in the Android Browser the drag and drop just have to add some lines:(function ($) {
     // Detect touch support
     $.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;
     // Ignore browsers without touch support
     if (!$.support.touch) {
     return;
     }
     var mouseProto = $.ui.mouse.prototype,
         _mouseInit = mouseProto._mouseInit,
         touchHandled;

     function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) { //use this function to simulate  etc,

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/     is supposed to capture the event has to touch as long as the browser is touch, but it does not work = (

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. This code works with Firefox, Chrome, IPad and Android. Just click on the corner.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>resizable demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
#resizable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        // Detect touch support
        $.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;
        // Ignore browsers without touch support
        if (!$.support.touch) {
        return;
        }
        var mouseProto = $.ui.mouse.prototype,
            _mouseInit = mouseProto._mouseInit,
            touchHandled;

        function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) { //use this function to simulate mouse event
        // Ignore multi-touch events
            if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
            return;
            }
        event.preventDefault(); //use this to prevent scrolling during ui use

        var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
            simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        // Initialize the simulated mouse event using the touch event's coordinates
        simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(
            simulatedType,    // type
            true,             // bubbles                    
            true,             // cancelable                 
            window,           // view                       
            1,                // detail                     
            touch.screenX,    // screenX                    
            touch.screenY,    // screenY                    
            touch.clientX,    // clientX                    
            touch.clientY,    // clientY                    
            false,            // ctrlKey                    
            false,            // altKey                     
            false,            // shiftKey                   
            false,            // metaKey                    
            0,                // button                     
            null              // relatedTarget              
            );

        // Dispatch the simulated event to the target element
        event.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
        }
        mouseProto._touchStart = function (event) {
        var self = this;
        // Ignore the event if another widget is already being handled
        if (touchHandled || !self._mouseCapture(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])) {
            return;
            }
        // Set the flag to prevent other widgets from inheriting the touch event
        touchHandled = true;
        // Track movement to determine if interaction was a click
        self._touchMoved = false;
        // Simulate the mouseover event
        simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseover');
        // Simulate the mousemove event
        simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousemove');
        // Simulate the mousedown event
        simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousedown');
        };

        mouseProto._touchMove = function (event) {
        // Ignore event if not handled
        if (!touchHandled) {
            return;
            }
        // Interaction was not a click
        this._touchMoved = true;
        // Simulate the mousemove event
        simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mousemove');
        };
        mouseProto._touchEnd = function (event) {
        // Ignore event if not handled
        if (!touchHandled) {
            return;
        }
        // Simulate the mouseup event
        simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseup');
        // Simulate the mouseout event
        simulateMouseEvent(event, 'mouseout');
        // If the touch interaction did not move, it should trigger a click
        if (!this._touchMoved) {
          // Simulate the click event
          simulateMouseEvent(event, 'click');
        }
        // Unset the flag to allow other widgets to inherit the touch event
        touchHandled = false;

        };
        mouseProto._mouseInit = function () {
        var self = this;
        // Delegate the touch handlers to the widget's element
        self.element
            .on('touchstart', $.proxy(self, '_touchStart'))
            .on('touchmove', $.proxy(self, '_touchMove'))
            .on('touchend', $.proxy(self, '_touchEnd'));

        // Call the original $.ui.mouse init method
        _mouseInit.call(self);
        };
    })(jQuery);


    </script>

    <div id="resizable"></div>

    <script>
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```